# In RxJava , Schedulers not offloading the work to io thread

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, micronaut

In the below code, i was expecting the Schedulers to offload the work from the main thread to the io thread, whereas on printing the logs, it seems like it is working on the same main thread.

```
        log.info("NIO Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Single<List<Product>> products  = recommendationService.getRecommendations(ids);
        log.info("NIO Response Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) ;
     products.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(s -> {
            log.info("Inside Map : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return s;
        })
                .subscribe( s -> log.info("Inside subscribe :" + s.get(0).getName()));

        log.info("After thread ");
        return products;
        //return  null;
    }
```

Logs :

```
16:17:49.226 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - NIO Thread : default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1
16:17:49.227 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationService - RecommendationService.getRecommendations() called...
16:17:49.240 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - NIO Response Thread : default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1
16:17:49.266 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - After thread 
16:17:52.097 [client1-nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - Inside Map : client1-nioEventLoopGroup-4-1
16:17:52.097 [client1-nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - Inside subscribe :Micronaut in Action
```

I was expecting it to execute the below two lines on `RxCachedSchedulerThread`, something like as below:

```
16:17:52.097 [RxCachedSchedulerThread-xx] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - Inside Map : RxCachedSchedulerThread-xx
16:17:52.097 [RxCachedSchedulerThread-xx] INFO  com.igaurav.RecommendationController - Inside subscribe :Micronaut in Action
```

**RecommendationService :**

```
 public Single<List<Product>> getRecommendations(List<String> ids) throws MalformedURLException {
        log.info("RecommendationService.getRecommendations() called...");
        return Observable.fromIterable(ids)
                .flatMap(id -> productClient.getProduct(id).toObservable())
                .toList();
    }
```

Comment: How is `recommendationService.getRecommendations` implemented?

Comment: Updated the RecommendationService method code

Comment: Okay, going deeper. How is `productClient.getProduct` implemented? Plus two general things: 1) `subscribeOn` may not affect the inner source in `flatMap`, 2) to ensure `map` and `subscribe` run on the desired thread, you'll have to use `observeOn`.

Comment: Also you return `products` which is the original, pre-subscribeOn source thus it won't be affected. In RxJava, sources are immutable and operators produce a new chain: `product` != `product.subscribeOn`.

Comment: How come the `product` is `pre-subscribeOn` ? Isn't it a  Single Observable which is yet to be subscribe ?